# Java Push Notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I want to implement push notification for Android and IOS, we have our own app for android and ios from that app user can send various request and after request completion user will get notification by using push notification.

So my question is
1. How I can detect the device to which i need to send notification.
2. I am new to GCM so can somebody help me from how to start this.
3. Every where I have found GCM send RegId to server, so whenever request comes every time I need to generate RegId or I need to check whether that user is registered or not if not register it first and then sends notification.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to regenerate the Registration ID every time.
In simple terms:

1. Client registers with GCM and client gets a registration ID.
2. You need to store the registration ID in your server.
3. Your server will need to send a list of registration ids with message content to GCM. GCM will respond with a list of successful and unsucessful messages to
   the server.
4. The push events that are successful will go to the corresponding device. Note that the push notification will only show if you have
   code on the client that receives it in addition you need to have the
   app installed.

The client and server code example on the documentation is easy to implement. Have fun :)